# Facebook RSS feeds ignoring HTTP ACCEPT header elements?

Tags: facebook, rss, http-headers

FB doesn't seem to respect ACCEPT headers sent to /feeds/page.php. See below example:

```
    GET /feeds/page.php?id=10036618151&format=rss20 HTTP/1.1
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    **Accept: text/xml,application/xml**
    Accept-Language: en-us
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
    Host: www.facebook.com

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    **Content-type: application/rss+xml**
    Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
    Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 10:05:49 -0800
    P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
    Pragma: no-cache
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Set-Cookie: datr=-vIzT4cxw52hjjqTfrpQkNYX; expires=Sat, 08-Feb-2014 16:23:22 GMT;path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly
    X-FB-Debug: qx/SiyRZDiVPm4wfiKVj37HImPoKM+DVAsO4oKSbSr0=
    X-Cnection: close
    Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2012 16:23:22 GMT
    Content-Length: 41236
```

I cannot seem to find a way to post a new bug report on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs, as I don't have the "Create" (nor the "Subscribe") buttons as described here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/559/

I have read that there are a fair few FB developers involved with this site, and was hoping that someone could shed some light on what I might be doing wrong / how to request FB changes the code to respect my request, or 406 me.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx MSXML < 6.0 responseXML Property only supports MIME types text/xml" & "application/xml". I know I could dump it out as text, then load it as XML through DOMDocument, but this would be extra code that is unnecessary for many of the other sites my code will be used with.

Comment: no - I mean your goal with this problem?  What problem is the header issue causing you?  Can you not get into the site?  Are you trying to write a script that interacts with Facebook's API?  Or is the problem that you can not open a bug report?

Comment: Cannot start bug report about the accept header not being respected. This issue causes the MSXML XML parser to halt on error "xml document must have a top level element". This does not happen on other sites which respect accept header and send back response with content-type either "text/xml" or "application/xml".

Comment: If your problem is about not being able to open a bug then this is not the place to seek help.  Your issue should be directed to Facebook.  https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Will re-ask my question on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/, per that groups info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How exactly is this behavior causing a problem for you?

Comment: This issue causes the MSXML XML parser to halt on error "xml document must have a top level element".

Comment: You are trying to parse Facebook's markup outside of a browser?

Comment: I am trying to parse RSS from FB in a script.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to verify yourself as a developer in order to create a bug.
Check out this link for verification via -

- [mobile number](https://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php)
- [credit card](https://www.facebook.com/login/reauth.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.facebook.com%2Fcards.php)

Once you have verified your account, head back to the bug system.

Comment: Didn't work. Used the mobile number verification method, received the code, typed it into that page, it added the number to my profile, but upon going back to the bug system no change. Do you have a screenshot of the location of the create button per chance (Perhaps I am blind)? Also, any other suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you need to create an application before filing a bug.  Also, the create button only appeared for me when I navigated the tabs on the left sidebar.

Comment: Hmmm... Have already browsed all tabs on the left sidebar (No luck). Now weird question time - Don't suppose you have code for a simple app I could use to "create an application"?. Hope this is not the solution as seems silly just to notify FB about a potential bug in their system.